# Laravel pivoting data in a view

Tags: php, laravel, view, pivot

I have the following two tables:

```
Items
    id
    name

Values
    id
    item_id
    value_date
    value
```

The relationship on Items is a hasMany(Value::class) and the relationship on Values is belongsTo(Item::class).  I want to display the data like this in a view:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
           | Item Name 1 | Item Name 2 | Item Name 3 | Item Name 3 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
01/01/2017 | Value       | Value       | Value       | Value       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
01/02/2017 | Value       | Value       | Value       | Value       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
01/03/2017 | Value       | Value       | Value       | Value       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
01/04/2017 | Value       | Value       | Value       | Value       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
01/05/2017 | Value       | Value       | Value       | Value       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I think I need to add the following pivot table to accomplish this:

```
Dates
    id
    date
    item_id
    value_id
```

But my question is how would I go about getting the Item names to build the header row?  Am I over complicating this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need a pivot table if you had a many-to-many relationship, which is not the case here.

You could use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
// Get ALL the Items, with their Values, ordered by Values.date 
$items = Items::with(['values' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('date', 'asc');
}])->get();

foreach ($items as $item) {

    // Item data
    var_dump($item->id);
    var_dump($item->name);

    // Values data (per Item)
    foreach ($item->values as $value) {

        var_dump($value->value);
        var_dump($value->date);

    }
}
```

Then it's just the matter of arranging it in your view.

Comment: Thanks for that.  It got me most of the way there.  Still working on getting it arranged properly.